# JS function breaking after for loop inside of for loop

Tags: jquery, json, clone

The purpose of this script is to dynamically create clones of elements and then populate the clones with data contained within a JS object. My objective is to return parsed JSON from the server, and call this function to clone elements within the DOM and populate these clones with the data from the server. The reason I would like this is to completely eliminate the dynamic creation of html elements from explicitly written JS strings, such as:

```
var HTMLelementAsJSstring = "<article></article>";
```

I would like these elements to be dynamically created by reading an object (eTreeObj) that contains the relationships of the elements to the parsed JSON (as JS object) properties.

Here is my JS (with jQuery)

```
var jso = {
"Result": [
    {
        "Title": "HQWE",
        "Details": "sdfsdf"
    },
    {
        "Title": "WQasdaE",
        "Details": "asdadas"
    }
    ]
};


function dynECreatefromJSO(Oproperty, parentE, childE, eTree) {
    for (i = 0; i <= Oproperty.length; i++) {

        if (i != 0) {
            var TargetE = Eclone.appendTo(parentE);
        } else {
            var TargetE = $(childE),
                Eclone = TargetE.clone();
        }

        for (q = 0; q <= eTree.length; q++) {
            TargetE.children(eTree[q].Element).html(Oproperty[i][eTree[q].JSOproperty]);
        }
        alert("DOESN'T REACH HERE");

    }
}

var eTreeObj = [ {
        "Element": "header",
        "JSOproperty": "Title"
        }, 
        {
        "Element": "article",
        "JSOproperty": "Details"
        }
    ];

dynECreatefromJSO(jso.Result, "div#main", "section.thiselement", eTreeObj);​
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="main"></div>

<section class="thiselement">
    <header></header>
    <article></article>
</section>​
```

The issue I am having occurs when I access the properties within the eTree object inside of the for loop where my incrementing variable is "q". The function breaks, and cannot run the loop with the incrementing variable "i" again.

If I remove the operations within this for loop, everything works fine. I cannot figure out why this is:

**http://jsfiddle.net/KKv22/2/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your loop like this,

```
for (i = 0; i < Oproperty.length; i++) {

    if (i != 0) {
        var TargetE = Eclone.appendTo(parentE);
    } else {
        var TargetE = $(childE),
            Eclone = TargetE.clone();
    }

    for (q = 0; q < eTree.length; q++) {
        TargetE.children(eTree[q].Element).html(Oproperty[i][eTree[q].JSOproperty]);
    }
    alert("DOESN'T REACH HERE");

}
```

This is because array index starts with 0(zero) So, it will contain items only upto length-1 index.